# Moment of inertia of hollow paraboloid

Tags: physics

A hollow paraboloid of length $l$ and radius $r$ with mass $m$ and uniform density $\rho$ has the origin at the base of its circular cross section, and at the center of its cross section. I am trying to find the moment of inertia for the axis that cuts through the paraboloid's center of gravity (its x axis) and the remaining axis y and z which should yield the same values of $I$ since it is axisymmetrical about the y and z axes. I have worked out the solution for what I believe is a filled paraboloid, but I am unsure how to calculate it for a hollow paraboloid, whether it be an infinitesimally small thickness or a uniform thickness $t$. I consider $x$ to be the distance from the origin of the paraboloid along the x axis towards the tip of the paraboloid.

$dm=\rho \pi r^2 dx$

$dI_x=\frac{1}{2}r^2dm$

$I_x=\int_0^l \frac{1}{2}r^2 \rho \pi r^2 dx$

$  = \frac{1}{2}r^4\rho \pi x|_0^l$

$I_y=I_z=\int_0^l (\frac{1}{4}r^2+x^2)\rho \pi r^2 dx$

$=(\frac{1}{4}\rho \pi r^4 x+\frac{1}{3}x^3\rho \pi r^2)|_0^l$

Revised solution (thanks to Math Lover)

$a$ is the constant that determines the shape of the nose cone of the paraboloid

$dI_x=\frac{1}{2}axdm$

$I_x=\int_0^l \frac{1}{2}a^2x^2 \rho \pi dx$

$I_x=\frac{1}{6}a^2x^3 \rho \pi$

$I_y=I_z=\int_0^l (\frac{1}{4}ax+x^2)\rho \pi ax dx$

$I_y=I_z=\int_0^l (\frac{1}{4}a^2x^2\rho \pi+ax^3\rho \pi ) dx$

$I_y=I_z=(\frac{1}{12}a^2x^3\rho\pi+\frac{1}{4}ax^4\rho \pi )$

Second revised solution (once again thanks to Math Lover)

Being a hollow paraboloid, we need to take the surface integral. For a hollow paraboloid we consider the surface area of everything but the base. This results in the equation:

$A=\frac{\pi b}{6h^2} [(b^2+4h^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}-b^3]$

Substituting base radius $b$ and height $h$ with our equivalent variables:

$A=\frac{\pi \sqrt{ax}}{6x^2} [(ax+4x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}-(ax)^{\frac{3}{2}}]$

Comment: This is wrong. Take $I_x$ for example. You are keeping $r$ constant which will give you moment of inertia of a cylinder. Even for what you are integrating, the integral is not correct. $\frac{1}{2} dm \ r^2$ does not expand to that.

Comment: Also note it is hollow.

Comment: Just made an edit for the $I_x$ term, but the result is the same. Indeed, $r$ is not constant. How can I write $r$ as a function of $x$?

Comment: Thank you. So that leaves $r=\sqrt{ax}$. Now for the thin shell, if I subtract the moment of inertia of a smaller paraboloid within the inside of this, would I obtain the effective moments of inertia?

Comment: Many thanks, I will take a look at this and hope to get a solution for you to validate.

Comment: Always kept that in mind. But as you can see I have never received an answer to my questions, aside from this one. If you mean to answer my own questions then indeed I could update my  questions with the solutions I came up with. I'll be sure to accept an answer here once I obtain the expression.

Comment: sorry I did not check that :) should have... by the way, for future, it is absolutely acceptable for you to add an answer of your own if you think it may help others.

Comment: Lastly, just check if you really need to find $I_y$ and $I_z$. Usually when we are asked to find moment of inertia for solid surfaces like cone, cylinder, paraboloid etc., it is about its symmetric axis (unlike a sphere). So is it something you have been specifically asked or is it your interpretation?

Comment: It is specific for my problem. I need to determine the inertia tensor for this shape.

Comment: Seems like I've gotten stuck. Where would I apply this surface integral? Do I completely rewrite the equations starting from the first integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a hollow paraboloid of length $L$ and radius $R$ along $x-$axis. If the equation of the paraboloid is $y^2 + z^2 = r^2 = ax$,

Then $R^2 = aL \implies a = \frac{R^2}{L}$. We will continue our working with $a$ and substitute this value of $a$ in the end.

As we know, moment of inertia of mass $dm$ around an axis = $dm \cdot r^2$

For a hollow paraboloid, $dm = \rho \ dS$ (where $\rho$ is the uniform density represented as mass per unit surface area)

$dS = \sqrt{1 + (\frac{\partial x}{\partial y})^2 + (\frac{\partial x}{\partial z})^2} \ dA = \sqrt{1 + (\frac{2y}{a})^2 + (\frac{2z}{a})^2} \ dA$

where $dA$ is the area of the projection of $dS$ in $YZ$ plane.

$dS = \frac{1}{a} \sqrt{a^2 + 4y^2 + 4z^2} \  dy \ dz = \frac{1}{a} \sqrt{a^2 + 4r^2} \ r \ dr \ d\theta$

So, $\displaystyle I_x = \frac{2 \pi \rho}{a} \int_0^R r^3 \ \sqrt{a^2 + 4r^2} \ dr$

For moment of inertia around $y$ or $z$ axis, we note that the radius is $\sqrt{r^2 + x^2}$.

So $\displaystyle I_y = I_z = \frac{2 \pi \rho}{a} \int_0^R r \big(r^2 + \frac{r^4}{a^2}\big) \ \sqrt{a^2 + 4r^2} \ dr$

Comment: Now the integral is not that straightforward. I know that hyperbolic substitution is one way to proceed. Also if you are working with numerical values of $R, L, a$ then WolframAlpha will also be able to provide definite integrals.

Comment: I'm still fairly perplexed about the solution. What is the term in front of $dA$? Also, I would substitute $r$ here for $\sqrt{ax}$ as well, correct?

Comment: If you look at the surface from positive $X$ side, what is the projection of the paraboloid in YZ plane? That is a circle, correct? The way calculation of surface area works is that you if you take a infinitely small surface area element $dS$, the factor in front of dA is the factor that translates area dA of the circle in YZ plane to the actual surface area element dS of the paraboloid. You may want to read this - https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/SurfaceIntegrals.aspx

Comment: To your second question about representing $r$ as a function of $x$, the answer is no. Since we are taking the projection in YZ plane, we will write it in terms of $r$ and integrate wrt $r$. If you integrate over $0 \leq r \leq R$ using the surface area formula, that already considers surface area of the paraboloid between $0 \leq x \leq L$. We already fixed $a$ according to $R$ and $L$.

Comment: Ok It took me a while to go through it but there are still some things that are not immediately intuitive to me. So R will be the radius at the length L of the paraboloid?

Comment: Yes, $R$ is the radius at $x = L$. See the first part where I am finding the value of $a$.